# I want to render the next page after rendering the first page but node.js won't do it

Tags: node.js, express

In my node.js app main process below, after the login process, if the user type = 'viewer', I render 'depot_list_pg' view. When the user selects a depot from the list by clicking a button, I want to render 'depot_details_pg' view. Everything works fine until the res.render in the 2nd app.post route at the end but no matter what I do, I can't get node.js to do the res.render there. Does anybody know how to do this?

**Main process: server_main2.js**

```
// Route to authenticate the user
app.post('/server_main2', (req, res, next) => { 
    var clientid = req.body.clientid;
    var userid = req.body.userid;
    var userpwd = req.body.userpwd;
    if (clientid && userid && userpwd) {  //Check if user has entered clientid, userid and userpwd in the login form.
        con.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE clientid = ? AND userid = ? AND userpwd = ?', [clientid, userid, userpwd], function(err, row) {   
                req.session.row = row;
                if (row.length > 0) {  //If user name/pwd is found in db,
                        req.session.userid = userid;  //save user name input from user.
                        req.session.loggedin = true;
                        if (row[0].usertype == 'admin') { //If user is an administrator,
                            res.render('admin_menu_pg')  //display admin menu page.
                        } else if (row[0].usertype == 'usermgm') {  // If user is from client management,
                                    res.render('usermgm_menu_pg')  //display client management menu page.
                               } else if (row[0].usertype == 'viewer') {  // if user is of viewer type. 
                                        get_depot_list(clientid, function(response){ // Call function to get list of depots for this client.
                                            data = response
                                            res.render('depot_list_pg',{data}) // Display water depot list page.
                                        }) 
                } else {
.
.
})
//Route to display depot details page.
app.post('/depot_details_pg', (req, res) => { 
    var depot_name = req.body.depot_name;  // Save depot name from jquery and save it in a variable.
        // Below, we retrieve data from water_depots table for the selected depot name. 
        con.query('SELECT * FROM water_depots WHERE depot_name = ?', [depot_name], function(err,data) { 
            if (data.length > 0) {  // If a row is found 
                res.render('depot_details_pg', {data}) //Display depot_details_pg view
            }   
        }); 
});
```

**Below is the code for depot_list_pg.ejs**

```
<script>
        function get_depot_name() {    
            $("#depselect_btn").click(function(){
                var activeRow=$(this).closest("tr");
                var depot_name=activeRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
                $.post({
                    url: '/depot_details_pg', data: {depot_name: depot_name}, dataType: 'json', success: function(response){}
                })
            }) 
        }    
</script>
.
.
<tbody>
<% if(data.length){
    for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {%> 
            <tr>
                <td><%=data[i].clientid%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].depot_name%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].city%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].town%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].willage%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].number_of_pumps%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].depot_status%></td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="get_depot_name()" name="depselect_btn" id="depselect_btn" class="depselect_btn">Depoyu seç</button></td>
                <td></td>                                 
            </>
    <%}
        }else{ %>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">Gosterilecek veri yok</td>
            </tr>
            <% } %> 
</tbody>
```

Comment: Your code does not make sense. HTTP is a request->response protocol. Once you've rendered a template you've sent the response. You can't send two responses for a single request.

Comment: I tried doing it in a seperate request outside this one but it didn't work. Please tell me how to do it because I spent over month on this but no luck.

Comment: You need some sort of condition to decide when to call render. As @slebetman mentions, you can't _render_ twice. As a render basically completes a response to send it back, which means at that point the ship has left the docks and you cannot change its contents. The user is already receiving those other ender bytes and rendering them.

Comment: I am new to node.js but I knew that you could only do 1 res.render per request. So, I tried doing it in a seperate app.post request but I had no luck. Out of my desperation, I put it back inside main process request which was wrong. I think in a new request outside the main one, I need to check if the button is clicked in the 1st form then render the 2nd view. However, this is all being done on server side where I don't know how to check for a button click. I am thinking of passing a parameter from the form to the main route to indicate a button click then render it.  Am I on the right path?

Comment: You will have to use some sort of session middleware that will keep track of that specific users 'session', after which you can record the users click be creating a route that will store the fact that the click occurred in the session, so you can choose what output to render in the next request to the other url.

Comment: I have revised the code. I now have a seperate app.post after the first app.post where I check if button is clicked and if so I render the 2nd view. But, I still have no luck. Something is missing but I don't know what it is.

Comment: There is so much clutter in your code, you should bring this back to a simpeler example. You don't need the queries etc... You are trying to let a click get you a different outcome. However, it might just be simpler to have two routes and manage the click part in the front end. Also `req.params.click` will never be `"y"` because you set it to something else the line before, inside your `console.log( req.params.click = ', req.params.click' )`. Also, your front-end should be passing in the `y` anyway, so your front-end would be managing this regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this mystery thanks to a node.js programmer. The problem is that the front-end will only allow 1 view to be rendered on the same window. To render additional views, you need to ask for a new window to be created on the client side using window.location.href. Then the res.render on the server side will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot render twice as the render function fires the http response, however I don't think that is the actual concern here as you don't ever call render twice in a single code path.

Let's dive into a few things.

Your second endpoint needs some work. I would change that endpoint to something like "/depot_details/:name" and render each details link in your depot_list view with the depot name. Depending on your template engine, something like:

```
<a href="/depot_details/{depotData[i].name}"></a>
```

So your endpoint would be:

```
app.post('/depot_details/:name', (req, res) => { ...
```

But let's dive deeper:

You are going to remove this code since you only need the name at this point, but I figured I'd point it out: you are reassigning req.params.click in the second console.log function:

```
console.log(req.params.click = ', req.params.click' )
```

so it will never have the value of "y" and therefore the controller will never get to the water_depot query. I'm guessing you were going for this instead:

```
console.log('req.params.click = ', req.params.click)
```

Another note for you: I'm not sure how con.query is processed but the raw SQL statement where you are selecting a user (first controller) might be exploitable as you could submit something like "admin'; #" and comment out the rest of the statement allowing user authentication without knowing the password. This is called SQL injection. If you still want to use raw SQL and not stored procedures or an ORM it may be best to check for the password first:

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE userpwd = ? AND clientid = ? AND userid = ?', [userpwd, clientid, userid]
```

One last thing: from the code I can infer you are storing plaintext passwords in you database which is a security risk. I would recommend that you use a hashing library like bcrypt, hash the password on sign up, store the hash to the database, and when people sign in, hash the submitted password with the same algorithm and compare that hash to the hashed password in the database (via the query).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed suggestions. I have tried them but still no luck. I have revised the main route and the depot_list_pg code as you see now. I have removed the route parameter altogether as you can see and this is the closest I can get to the 2nd res.render line. It does everthing but it just won't render depot_details_pg view. Perhaps you can make some more suggestions if you have the time. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but can you throw a console.log in that details route to see if you ever get to the query and report back? And if you think you're not hitting that route at all, try using cURL or Postman to send a post request directly to that post route with a known depot_name in the request body. What we are trying to solve here is whether the issue lies with the post route or if the front end list page links need attention.

Comment: I have console.log lines before and after res.render and they both get executed. I have removed them in my stack overflow posting. This means that it hits the app.post route, it runs every line in the route except the res.render line. No error emessages, it seems to just ignore the res.render.